# JSON return from AJAX callback not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, salesforce

My AJAX function (in coffeescript) is returning values, but neither the `error` nor the `success` callback are fired.

```
$ ->
  $('#sf_field').autocomplete
    source: (request, response) ->
      $.ajax
        url: 'https://XXXXX.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/search/suggestions'
        type: 'GET'
        contentType: 'application/json'
        cache: false,        
        crossDomain: true
        dataType: 'json'
        beforeSend: (xhr) ->
          xhr.setRequestHeader 'Authorization', 'Bearer XXXX.XXXXX'
          return
        data: {
            q:  request.term,
            sobject: 'Contact'
          }
    success: (data) ->
      console.log "success"
      alert "success"
      json = $.parseJSON(data)
    error: () ->
      console.log "error"
      alert "error"
    complete: () ->
      console.log "complete"
      alert "complete"
    select: (event, ui) ->
      $("#sf_id").val(ui.item.id)
  return
```

I see in the firefox console, the XHR results are there in correct JSON format (validated on jsonlint) , but the callbacks seem not be fired, I can't see the suggestions in the UI (not even the log messages in the console do appear).

The resulting JSON from the browsers XHR-response window:

```
{
"autoSuggestResults":[{"attributes":{"type":"Contact",
"url":"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Contact/XXXXAU"},
"Id":"XXXXXX01uQoVQAU",
"Name":"Martin Aaaaaa"},
{"attributes":{"type":"Contact",
"url":"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Contact/XXXXuQoZQAU"},
"Id":"XXXXXZQAU",
"Name":"Martin Bbbbbb"},
{"attributes":{"type":"Contact",
"url":"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Contact/XXXXojQAE"},
"Id":"XXXXXojQAE",
"Name":"Martin Cccccc"},
{"attributes":{"type":"Contact",
"url":"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Contact/XXXXQn5QAE"},
"Id":"XXXXXQn5QAE",
"Name":"Thomas Martin Dddddd"},
{"attributes":{"type":"Contact",
"url":"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Contact/XXXXQv7QAE"},
"Id":"XXXXX0001uQv7QAE",
"Name":"Martin Eeeeee"}],
"hasMoreResults":true,
"meta":{"nameFields":[{"entityApiName":"Contact",
"fieldApiName":"Name"}],
"secondaryFields":[]}
}
```

I have tried with various dataType: (jsonp, text, html), but this doesn't help
Thanks for your hints

Comment: `success ` and other callback should be indented under `$ajax`

Comment: I for the life of me cannot see why people use coffeescript over ES6.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by PGill, The intendation was the problem.
Therefore, my coffeescript should look like:

```
$ ->
  $('#sf_field').autocomplete
    source: (request, response) ->
      $.ajax
        url: 'https://XXXXX.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/search/suggestions'
        type: 'GET'
        contentType: 'application/json'
        cache: false,        
        crossDomain: true
        dataType: 'json'
        beforeSend: (xhr) ->
          xhr.setRequestHeader 'Authorization', 'Bearer XXXX.XXXXX'
          return
        data: {
            q:  request.term,
            sobject: 'Contact'
          }
        success: (data) ->
          console.log "success"
          alert "success"
          json = $.parseJSON(data)
        error: () ->
          console.log "error"
          alert "error"
        complete: () ->
          console.log "complete"
          alert "complete"
        select: (event, ui) ->
          $("#sf_id").val(ui.item.id)
  return
```